# Mobile view for SharePoint WCM sites

Tags: mobile, wcm

I have a client who is planning to make their SP2010 internet facing website viewable on modern mobile devices (mostly iPads). The site is basically a publishing site with many wiki and publishing subsites. Also, the site branding is customized with custom master page, stylesheets and images. Additionally the site contains few custom developed webparts that displays data from databases.

I don't want to restrict features of SP2010 (or customizations applied to the existing site) when it is viewed on iPads or other tablets. The solution must be a futturistic one and i have to keep the fact in my mind that mobile web experience is getting improved day by day. Also I don't have a bandwidth to re-develop the existing pages or webparts to suit mobile view. The fastest and stable solution I can think of within these constraints is developing a new light weight, XHTML complaint (may be HTML 5) for the existing site to a better mobile experience.

I would request community to help me to decide on the best possible solution to make this site browsable on popular smart phones.

I have gone through some really nice blog posts and discussions that made me think in this direction. Many thanks for those people who shared their experiences.

[Don’t use SharePoint 2010’s mobile view for internet presence sites](http://nadirkamdar.blogspot.in/2011/03/dont-use-sharepoint-2010s-mobile-view.html)

I have posted same question in MSDN forums. [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/sharepoint2010general/thread/36609df9-38b6-4dbf-8427-7d32a7c2327b) is the url

Thanks in advance
Arun

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have been going through this but Waldek M. has a really nice write-up providing valuable hints on the subject, find it here http://blog.mastykarz.nl/conditional-content-mobile-devices-sharepoint-2010/ also check this for some more details http://www.bloggix.com/archive/2011/01/31/introduction-to-mobile-pages-in-sharepoint-2010/